# Cannot retrieve access tocken

Tags: authentication, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am experimenting with this https://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/# using the gitlab code. I can display it locally (without the engine or dataflow) but I can not gain an access token.

I am using the VSCode extension and I get the code 401 (Unauthorized) error if I try to create buckets etc (hence why I am trying to get an access code). However, when I request one using this:

curl -i -X POST  'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate'  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -d 'client_id=-----'  -d 'client_secret= ----'  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'  -d 'scope=data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete'

I get this error:

Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Collections.IDictionary".
At line:1 char:90

- ... ticate'  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -d 'cl ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRe
    questCommand

I have no idea where I am going wrong and have tried everything I can think of.

Hope you can help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing 401 issues when working with the Forge extension for Visual Studio Code, make sure that you have at least one "environment" configured with your Forge client ID and secret. When you activate the extension for the first time, it should ask you for the credentials automatically, but you can also add or edit the environments at any point by going to the Visual Studio Code preferences, and looking for "forge":

[image: Find Forge Settings]

And then, in the *Autodesk > Forge: Environments* section, hit the *Edit in settings.json* link and edit the environments directly as JSON, creating a new object (with `title`, `clientId`, and `clientSecret` properties set) if needed:

[image: Edit Forge Environments]

> Btw. VSCode provides intelli-sense support when editing the *settings.json* file, so you'll see exactly which properties are expected/available in each environment.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention - when you update your VSCode preferences, you'll most likely need to reload the editor, or at least open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows I think), and use the "Developer: Reload Window" command.

Comment: Thank you! haha yess after being stuck for hours it was all solved by restarting everything

Answer (score 0):

It defaults to Invoke-WebRequest.
Try to use Invoke-RestMethod like this:

```
$Body = @{
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    client_id = ""
    client_secret = ""
    scope = "data:write data:read bucket:create bucket:delete"
}
$Headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -Headers $Headers -Body $Body
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly nothing happens when I use this